# How to encrypt a String in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, encryption

I am kind of new to coding and in this particular situation I am trying to change each character in a string.

My first attempt is to use a pointer to access each character (since I think it is some sort of an array so I won´t need an index for loop) and change it to '%'

Else I want to change the current location of the pointer to be +5 letters in the alphabet.
At the ende the pointer should move one forward.

So this string = "This is confidential information"
should look like this = "Ymnx%nx%htsknijsynfq%nsktwrfynts"

There is an Error at line 22 at the "if" statement where i want change the empty char to %

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void encryptString(char *sPtr);

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "This is confidential information"; //given string to encrypt

    printf("The string before encrypting is: %s", string);

    encryptString(string);

    printf("\nThe string after encrypting is: %s\n", string);

}

void encryptString(char *sPtr)
{

    while(*sPtr != '\0'){   //loop is running until end of string
        if(*sPtr == ''){    // should convert space char into a '%')
            char *sPtr = '%';
        }
        else{              //should shift the output of character +5 in the alphabet
            char *sPtr =+ 5;
        }
    ++sPtr;               //make sPtr point to the next character
    }
}
```

Comment: ```''``` this is not a space, this is nothing. You should write ```' '```

Comment: The sequence `''` is invalid in C unless it is inside a string.  You need to use `' '` for blank, `'\0'` for the null byte, `'\''` for a single quote.

Comment: Please enable warnings on your compiler, and heed them. For gcc this would be "-Wall -Wextra". At the very least you are declaring new variables called sPtr in both branches of your if/else, and assigning them values. Should be if (foo == ' ') { *sPtr = '%';}. Same for the else case.

Comment: Beware `foo =+ 5` vs `foo += 5`.  The first is like `foo = (+5)`  the second is like `foo = foo + 5`

Comment: Yeah I don´t unterstand a thing. I am going back to learn more of the basics.

Comment: @Wyck FWIW, in early C, operands `+=` and `=+` did the same thing.

Comment: `while(*sPtr) { *sPtr++ += 5; }` looks nearly sufficient.

Comment: What do you want to have happen to a `z` that gets shifted _+5 letters in the alphabet_?  ASCII codes are not the same as _the alphabet_.  The ASCII code for `z` is 122, plus 5 gives you 127, which is **DEL**, which is not even a printable character.

Comment: @Wyck . As I am a beginner I asked the question to myself but have enough to do with the given task. 
It worked with the given string but what happens after letter z is another question to think about.

Comment: @Staytuned42 consider a _wrap-around_ technique.  Get the _position_ of the letter in the alphabet by subtracting the code for `a`.  Then add 5.  Then take this number modulo the number of letters in the alphabet, then add back in the code for `a` to get an ASCII code again.  You'll have three cases, one where the letter is an upper case [A-Z] and one where it is lower case [a-z], and one where it is a space.  `((c-'a'+5)%26)+'a'` and `((c-'A'+5)%26)+'a'`, and for a space, just `'%'`.  Now you should also decide what to do with other pesky punctuation such as period, comma, etc.?

Comment: @Wyck thank you for the suggestion. I will try to find a solution! I need to dig deeper into how to apply ASCII to my code.

Answer (score 1):

There were some issues in your code, especially the way your have written `x =+ 5`. Also, I don't understand why you added the `char` in front of the assignment `char *sPtr =+ 5`. <s>As it is written C interprets this as a cast to char, but dereferencing a pointer to char already has the `char` type, so it is useless at least and dangerous at most.</s>. It actually creates a new variable that shadows the outer sPtr, sets it to point to some weird low memory location, then doesn't dereference it

Lastly you can think about what happen when the alphabet is finished, for instance when there is a `z` character. I have here your code fixed with an idea on how to wrap around with a ASCII table. Please mind that the C standard does not HAVE TO use ASCII, so this implementation won't work everywhere, it's more of an idea for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define START_ALPHABET_ASCII 65
#define ALPHABET_LENGTH_ASCII (123-START_ALPHABET_ASCII)

void encryptString(char *sPtr);

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "This is confidential information zzz"; //given string to encrypt

    printf("The string before encrypting is: %s", string);

    encryptString(string);

    printf("\nThe string after encrypting is: %s\n", string);

}

void encryptString(char *sPtr)
{
    
    while(*sPtr != '\0'){   //loop is running until end of string
        
        if(*sPtr == ' '){    // should convert space char into a '%')
           *sPtr = '%';
        }
        else{              //should shift the output of character +5 in the alphabet
           *sPtr = ((*sPtr)+5 - START_ALPHABET_ASCII)%(ALPHABET_LENGTH_ASCII) + START_ALPHABET_ASCII ;
        }
       ++sPtr;               //make sPtr point to the next character
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
The string before encrypting is: This is confidential information zzz
The string after encrypting is: Ymnx%nx%htsknijsynfq%nsktwrfynts%EEE
```

Comment: Good answer, other than that the extra "char" makes a pointless cast. It actually creates a new variable that shadows the outer sPtr, sets it to point to some weird low memory location, then doesn't dereference it.

Comment: Ah! That's it, because it is at the other side of the equal sign, and it's "acting on" a "lvalue", I guess. Thanks, I will update the answer.

Comment: Magic  numbers 65 and 123 deserve explanation.  The role of doing `%(ALPHABET_LENGTH_ASCII)` is questionable - yet OP's post is unclear on `z`, or other extreme characters.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I guess that the wordly define's name + the note on the usage of ASCII table is enough info. The modulo operation is to wrap, if you have a better idea just write it, I am happy to edit the answer. OP's is unclear, true, but it's an helpful advice for free, what is wrong with it?

Comment: what is wrong with it: `%(ALPHABET_LENGTH_ASCII)` will also wrap characters outside the alphabet to alphabet letters making decoding to the original string impossible.  Consider using `'A'`, `('z' + 1)` versus 65, 123 to improve clarity.

Comment: @n.m. dude, manners.

Comment: Thank you @everyone I am going back to my basement and recap all this new information! Much love to this community